# Inconsistent border width in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm experiencing inconsistent border width when rendering a box with 1px wide border. This is obviously due to browser scaling (I'm on a 2160 x 1440 monitor). While I realize the "a pixel is not a pixel" problem (due to scaling), I still think the width of the border should be the same across all sides of the box, shouldn't it?

This issue occurs on Chrome and IE, but both Firefox and Opera handles it perfectly. As you can see the left and bottom border is a bit wider than the top and right one.

[image]

Here's my code:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Is there a good solution to this?

I will add that I'm on a Surface Pro 3. It might have something to do with scaling in Windows.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. It sounds like a Chrome bug more than anything though.

Comment: Neither I can reproduce, voting to close.

Comment: @MightyPork Why? Are you implying that I'm making this up?

Comment: No, just that it's not something we'll be able to solve. If it's a bug in chrome, report it to Chromium bugtracker. Also, it's not an error we can reproduce, so it's likely specific to your setup.

Comment: Can you please chack that your browser isn't zoomed?

Comment: @try-catch-finally It's default 100 %.

Comment: The box created by your code snippet is smaller than what the picture shows is this due to the fact that you'Ve screenshotted another box? I assume the error occures on the box rendered with your code snippet too? Please check this error on another system with the same browser version. Please add the exact browser and OS versions.

Comment: This is still an issue in both Firefox and Chrome. The only solution I've found is to adjust the border width based on the device pixel ratio. I use the following JS for a 1px width but you could probably achieve a similar result using media queries. `((window.devicePixelRatio >= 2 ? 2 : 1) / window.devicePixelRatio)+'px'`

Answer (score 1):

As you said, this is related to browser scaling. I see this often inside of Chrome with Windows 10's Display Scaling set to 150%, one of the defaults for UHD monitors.

I'm unsure of the compatibility for Opera and Safari, but this worked in Firefox, Edge, and Chrome for me:

```
border-width:0.1px;
```

Comment: I run into this issue sometimes, especially because my system has 125% display scaling, the recommended scaling for 1440p displays on Windows 10. Using a value smaller than a pixel helps make it exactly a pixel even post-scaling.

The right solution to this problem would be to have a way to force a container to be aligned to the display's physical pixel boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Didn't help me.  I even tried `border: thin solid blue;`

Comment: I have put the rule for div with the problematic border's width and it worked for me.